# Where to Store xkeycaps output in Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: 14.04

I have to use xkeycaps to exchange a pair of keys in Ubuntu 14.04.1. I haven't been able to find where to store the rewritten keycaps file so that it will load at startup. There is a 3-year-old message in Ask Ubuntu, but it doesn't work. I'd appreciate it if someone could explain the location and anything that has to be done.